# ms sql server READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Fatal Current Process Error (severity level 20)",
"SQL Server instance raised the following fatal message: Error: 7886, Severity: 20, State: 2. 
A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. 
A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.
This connection will be terminated..

Ребята, подскажите, как чинить?
Ошибка валится второй день.

Comment: 1) А у Вас действительно используется уровень изоляции READ UNCOMMITTED или запрос с хинтом NOLOCK? Если да, то действительно ли он Вам нужен? 2) что говорит DBCC CHECKDB? 3) Установлены ли все апдейты/сервиспаки?

Comment: 1) Используется ReadComitted, а какой запрос - не поймем. 2) Вроде, ошибок нет, сейчас добавлю листинг. 3) Это я вообще не знаю, что такое

Comment: 3) Что пишет `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Service Broker Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9670, State 1: Remote Service Bindings analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9605, State 1: Conversation Priorities analyzed: 0.
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrscols'.
There are 4873 rows in 49 pages for object "sys.sysrscols".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsets'.
There are 1158 rows in 13 pages for object "sys.sysrowsets".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclones'.
...
И дальше он большой.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64)   Apr 27 2017 17:36:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Было бы наверно полезно обновиться, после вашей версии выходил еще целый сервис-пак, и уже куча cumulative updates к нему. Но не факт, что в вашей конкретной ситуации это поможет. Надо ловить, на каком запросе падает (Profiler в помощь). Пишут, что эта ошибка обычно вылетает, когда во время грязного чтения параллельно удаляются читаемые данные.